# uiwebview does not work if i change something in address bar?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

When I type https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/united_kingdom in webview address bar it works, but if type https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/united kingdom it does not...

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have spaces in a url, thats why its not working!

Edit: 
To avoid having spaces in your url, you can check if the url has got any spaces, and if, show an alert.

```
if([url.text rangeOfString:@" "].location != NSNotFound) {
    //url contains a space, show an alert and don't load the request here!
}
else {
    //load the request into your webview!
}
```

Comment: @mukesh hey ive added some code to the post. It should be helpful. Please accept the answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

Browsers does not allow blanks spaces. 
Web Browser (desktop) like chrome, ie etc automatically convert blanks spaces to percent sign %. To do this on objective c you need to encapsulate it with `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` method. Below is a working example.

```
NSString *myUrl = @"http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/united kingdom";
[myUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```